# rand() doesn't follow Gaussian Distribution & Central Limit Theorem

Tags: c, random

I've created a program that use rand() to generate repeated number in C.

However the repeated number doesn't follow [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)

Can anyone solve this rand() bug problem or is there an alternative other than using rand() C library to generate better random number?

Here's the screen shot: [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>


#define TOTAL_THROW 10000000

typedef enum _COINTOSS {
    UNDEFINED = 0,
    HEAD = 1,
    TAIL = 2
} COINTOSS;

COINTOSS toss_coin () {
    int x = rand() % 2;
    if (x == 0) return HEAD;
    else if (x == 1) return TAIL;
}

void main () {
    int x, i, j, v1 = 0, v2 = 200, total = 0;
    int head_range[25] = {0};
    int tail_range[25] = {0};
    int no_range = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int repeated = 0;
    COINTOSS previos_toss = UNDEFINED;
    COINTOSS current_toss;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<TOTAL_THROW; i++) {
        current_toss = toss_coin();             // current toss
        if (previos_toss == current_toss) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (current_toss == HEAD) head_range[count] += 1;
            else if (current_toss == TAIL) tail_range[count] += 1;


            previos_toss = current_toss;
            count = 0;
        }

    }

    for (i=24; i>=0; i--) {
        printf("+%d = %d\n", i+1, head_range[i]);
    }

    puts("________________\n");

    for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
        printf("-%d = %d\n", i+1, tail_range[i]);
    }

    printf("\nTOTAL_THROW: %d\n", TOTAL_THROW);


    printf("\nPress [ENTER] to exit. . .");
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is using modulus to get your random number into the required range, which uses the lower bits (it's a classic gotcha):

```
int x = rand() % 2;
```

The lower bits of `rand()`  (a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG)) are not as random as the high bits. This applies to all LCG's regardless of library or language.

For a range of [0..N), you should do something like this (which uses the high bits):

```
int r = rand() / ( RAND_MAX / N + 1 );
```